# iam_assumable_role_custom with inline_policy

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I've created a terraform to integrate newrelic with my aws using terraform-aws-iam

```
# terraform {
module "iam_assumable_role_custom" {
  source                   = "../../../modules/aws-iam/modules/iam-assumable-role"
  create_role              = true
  role_name                = "NewRelicInfrastructure-Integrations"
  trusted_role_arns        = ["arn:aws:iam::754728514883:root"]
  role_sts_externalid      = ["3202355"]
  attach_readonly_policy   = true
  readonly_role_policy_arn = var.readonly_arn
  custom_role_policy_arns = [
    aws_iam_policy.NewRelicBudget.arn
  ]
  number_of_custom_role_policy_arns = 1
}
```

For now I have to create another policy and put it in the module as `aws_iam_policy.NewRelicBudget` so does this part of the module is not support inline_policy?

Comment: Are you referring to / using https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws/latest/submodules/iam-assumable-role ?

Comment: If so: yes, this module does not support inline policies.

Comment: What benefit are you getting from that module over using the `aws_iam_role` resource directly? It looks overly complex but not really composing anything useful to me at a quick glance.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's look like that module not really support `inline_policy` so I just create from scratch and it 100% easy than using the module =))